# saving data in asp.net form temporarily

Tags: asp.net, tempdata

I have one requirement of saving data in asp.net form temporarily. I want to re load the saved data in form controls, if on any error or session time out.
Can any body give solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Increase Session time out in web config.

Answer (score 0):

Save the data in hidden fields as you enter data in hidden fields on key press..Use angular-js for this which makes your work easy,since it supports two way binding.

Upon session expiry retrive the data in hidden fields to the user controls.

The second option is Use Update Panel in the ajax tool kit.

Happy Coding